# looking for a non-blocking way to handle events in a certain route

Tags: apache-camel, rx-java

I am considering which technology to use for the following use case:

the system is event driven
there is a flow (which is mostly without forks except for error handling)
the flow itself should be sync , but non-blocking

the possibilities I have so far are:

1. pure java -
   this make the code not so clear as I have to nest the callbacks inside one another
   and have to write everything myself
2. apache-camel - use the camel routes 
   i.e.:

```
 
    from(URI)
    .transform(creatUserExpression) //prepare msg to send to db
    .inOut(DB.URI) //send to db
    .transform(UserCreatedExpression) //prepare msg to send to next step
    .inout(OtherService.URI) 
    .end();
```

this looks like a nice solution, but is camel suited to handling all my business logic - all the flows for the events? 
camel is mostly used for integration between services, so we are not sure if it would be correct to use it for the business logic

3. java RX - looks like a possible option , still don't know it enough, and is it production ready?
   current release is 0.20.7 - not yet a 1.X version
4. akka - tried to use it for the flow - but in order to make sure the flows goes only 1 way we needed to use FSM which caused the code to be too complicated and we decided against it
5. any other suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: 3. the 1.0.0 version of RxJava is out since last week. (And was already in use at Netflix, in SoundClound Android App, ...)

By the way, if you can't decide between Rx and/or Camel, an RxJava Camel endpoint exist (I haven't looked into it)

Comment: I now see that they changed the name in maven repository - it is now under io.reactivex/rxjava and not com.netflix.rxjava » rxjava-core (which is still 0.20.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that most of the time you typically try and stay clear from as much business logic in Integration routes. Business logic on a ESB is typically a big no, some of the more rigid architects I have known will break into violent swearing when they see business logic in the integration layer. This point of view makes sense when you are using a ESB system to integrate services.

In a SOA/Services world you don't want the producers and consumers to be tightly coupled and adding business logic to the integration layer breaks that abstraction. A consumer should be able to consume data from a SAP system, C# web service, Java service or any other service without knowing how the producer work. It should just understand the data.

Apache Camel is not a ESB, it is a EIP toolkit/framework. You can use Apache camel in a client application as well. This is the one of the reasons I really have a soft spot for Camel. It is library I can use to create integration routes. It is flexible and can be used by itself without the need for a full scale server.

So in your case I don't see a problem using apache camel for this purpose. If you are going to install ServiceMix, FuseESB or another full ESB system you are just going to overly complicate the whole setup.

My suggestion(it is just a suggestion) is that in this case having business logic in your route is not going to be bad as this is not really(from your description) about integration but leveraging the power of Camel to create and maintain a event system. Remember Camel does not come with a runtime environment so you still need to host this route somewhere. A simple run time container would be Apache Karaf. You can use this OSGi kernel to install and run your routes on. Last time I check the Karaf project was like under 40MB unzipped so compared to some of the other run times it is really small.

I have used Camel in this fashion to create and host services for android client for example. I guess my main message is that Camel can be considered as a routing engine or routing engine builder which specialises in integration. Camel is not an ESB so the concerns about business logic in here is not always applicable.

Comment: thanks for your input, I also feel that it is more about leveraging the power of Camel, it make the code clearer and maintainable